# How to use handler thread for multi threading

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I'm trying to move multiple markers on google map and each in separate thread. Currently I am using java thread class inside loop to create separate thread for each vehicle. Here is the sample code:

```
private void proceedToMoveVehicle(ArrayList<RealTimeDetailsResponce> sourceList, ArrayList<RealTimeDetailsResponce> destinationList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < destinationList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sourceList.size(); j++) {
            if (destinationList.get(i).getVehicleNo().equalsIgnoreCase(sourceList.get(j).getVehicleNo())) {
                final com.google.maps.model.LatLng vehicleStartPositions = new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(sourceList.get(j).getLatitude(), sourceList.get(j).getLongitude());
                final double destainationLatitude = destinationList.get(i).getLatitude();
                final double destainationLongitude = destinationList.get(i).getLongitude();
                final String vehicleTitle = sourceList.get(j).getVehicleNo();
                final com.google.maps.model.LatLng vehicleEndPositions = new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(destainationLatitude, destainationLongitude);
                final double speedValue = 0.0000;
                if (vehicleStartPositions.lat != vehicleEndPositions.lat || vehicleStartPositions.lng != vehicleEndPositions.lng) {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getPathyFromDirectionAPiRequestNew(vehicleStartPositions, vehicleEndPositions, vehicleTitle);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    moveVehicle(vehicleTitle, speedValue);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting vehicle's updated location from server after every 5 seconds. Here, the draw back is I'm not able to reuse these threads again once i get the updated location and again I have to create a new thread.

I have heard about android handler thread, in that we can reuse a thread using Looper. Can someone help me to do this with handler thread.

Comment: Aren't you talking about putting this inside an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) class?

Comment: No, I am asking about Handler Thread.

Comment: Why don't you use executorservice for doing in different threads?

Comment: Okay, can you please share sample code for executorservice.

Comment: My question is simply why do you want to do it like this ? In my opinion is the worst approach possible, first you don't have control over the  threads, if you close the activity/fragment and there are running threads you'll probably get a crash, spawning a lot of threads here won't speed up the the app, it will probably get worse results since you update the UI thread from all of them, I would suggest to bundle the update in an async task or job scheduler and update the UI thread when a set of cars are updated.

Comment: @danypata This approach will lead to move vehicle one after other. My requirement is to move vehicle independently as per their location updates. Some vehicle can sit idle too if their location is not getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32); // you can number of threads you want

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
         //do your work1 here
    } 
});

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
         //do your work2 here and so on..
    } 
});
```

or you can put a loop.

Comment: Can you please let me know what are the advantages of using ExecutorService in loop rather than thread in loop ?  I mean I did not get that why this approach is better than the one I am using ?

Comment: You told that "the draw back is I'm not able to reuse these threads" right. If you use ExecutorService it automatically frees the thread once the work is finished, so that the thread can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Since `IntentService` is running on a `HandlerThread`, I assume that this will answer the question.

But the issue with `HandlerThread` is that it runs outside of your activity’s lifecycle (also `IntentService`), so it needs to be cleaned up properly or else you will have thread leaks.